# I need to arrange my list in a specific way - python

Tags: python, list, function, math, list-comprehension

Basically, the user enters any positive number and then the program should arrange a list, which contains all positive numbers up to that entered number so that the sum of 2 consecutive elements in the list is a square number. If the entered number doesn't allow that sorting I just want the program to print error. This is the code so far :

```
u = int(input("ENTER: "))
l = []
for i in range(1, u + 1):
    l.append(i)
o = l
t = []
for elem in l:
    for x in o:
        p = elem + x
        p = math.sqrt(p)
        if p%1 == 0:
            if x == elem:
                break
            else:
                t.append(x)
                t.append(elem)
```

If I, for example, enter 15 then the list t, in the end, looks like this :

```
[3, 1, 8, 1, 15, 1, 1, 3, 6, 3, 13, 3, 5, 4, 12, 4, 4, 5, 11, 5, 3, 6, 10, 6, 2, 7, 9, 7, 1, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 15, 10, 5, 11, 14, 11, 4, 12, 13, 12, 3, 13, 12, 13, 2, 14, 11, 14, 1, 15, 10, 15]
```

The list contains all pairs that in theory would work, I am stuck arranging this list so that every number appears once and that every consecutive numbers follow the property mentioned above.

So the list I am looking for in the end would be this :

```
[8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9]
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you know anything about graph theory or path seeking? You succeeded in finding all the connections between the numbers--now you need to find a "maximal path" that uses those connections. Search for and learn about those topics.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I do not feel right about that. My answer is based on that of Jayjayyy: the main ideas are his (or hers), while my changes improve the speed but are still relatively minor. He stimulated me to look closely at the problem and my purpose was to give back to the community, not to take away from him. I had previously solved a similar problem but his method was better than mine. Please accept his answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make some slight improvements to the answer by @Jayjayyy. This code, slightly modified from @Jayjayyy's, is somewhat more complicated but also faster. For `n = 15` this code is more than 7.5 times faster on my system, and for `n = 30` it is more than 19 times faster. This speed increase is done by reducing the number of checks that a sum is a square number and by speeding up those checks. I also moved the square-number check to reduce the number of times the routine calls itself.

Finally, I changed some variable names to be more self-documenting. But @Jayjayyy's code is still very praiseworthy for its simplicity.

```
import math

def f(listsofar, numbersleft):
    if not numbersleft:
        return listsofar
    result = False
    for i in numbersleft:
        if not listsofar or math.sqrt(listsofar[-1] + i).is_integer():
            result = f(listsofar + [i], [j for j in numbersleft if j != i])
            if result:
                break
    return result

n = int(input("Arrange numbers from 1 to ").strip())
numbers = list(range(1, n+1))
print("Input:", numbers)
print("Output:", f([], numbers))
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be kind of a brute force approach with a recursive function:

```
import math

def f(temp, numbers):
    for i, j in zip(temp[:-1], temp[1:]):
        sqrt = math.sqrt(i+j)
        if int(sqrt) != sqrt:
            return False
    if not numbers:
        return temp
    for i in numbers:
        result = f(temp + [i], [j for j in numbers if j != i])
        if result:
            break
    return result

n = int(input("Arrange numbers from 1 to ").strip())
numbers = list(range(1, n+1))
print("Input:", numbers)
print("Output:", f([], numbers))
```

Example with 4:

```
Arrange numbers from 1 to 4
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output: False
```

Example with 15:

```
Arrange numbers from 1 to 15
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Output: [8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9]
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy what does this line do : for i, j in zip(temp[:-1], temp[1:]):

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You can complete the last steps by using Graphs. The list t would be better off as as tuple pairs representing edges.

You can also modify the list later as follows.

```
t =[3, 1, 8, 1, 15, 1, 1, 3, 6, 3, 13, 3, 5, 4, 12, 4, 4, 5, 11, 5, 3, 6, 10, 6, 2, 7, 9, 7, 1, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 15, 10, 5, 11, 14, 11, 4, 12, 13, 12, 3, 13, 12, 13, 2, 14, 11, 14, 1, 15, 10, 15]
t = list(zip(t[::2],t[1::2]))
```

I would recommend modifying your original code slightly instead.

```
import networkx as nx
import math

u = int(input("ENTER: "))
l = []
for i in range(1, u + 1):
    l.append(i)
o = l
t = []
for elem in l:
    for x in o:
        p = elem + x
        p = math.sqrt(p)
        if p%1 == 0:
            if x == elem:
                break
            else:
                t.append((x, elem)) #to keep tuples instead
```

Now, Just turn it into a graph problem. Find all neighbours recursively till you get your maximum length. Keep track of what neighbours  you already visited to avoid traversing the same paths again.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(t)
#Now, you need to find "new" neighbours for all possible combinations that make the longest chain in your case
def findPaths(G, current_node, n, to_exclude = None):
    if to_exclude == None:
        to_exclude = set([current_node])
    else:
        to_exclude.add(current_node)
    if n==1:
        return [[current_node]]
    paths = [[current_node]+path for neighbor in G.neighbors(current_node) if neighbor not in to_exclude for path in findPaths(G,neighbor,n-1,to_exclude)]
    to_exclude.remove(current_node)
    return paths


allpaths = []
for node in G:
    allpaths.extend(findPaths(G, node, G.number_of_nodes()))
if allpaths:
    print('match found')
    [print(x) for x in allpaths]
else:
    print('no matches')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used two For Loops , Your typically adding the same numbers to each other , not the next in list so 
(elem in l == x in o)  is always true

and when you used (p%1 == 0)  another always True

and to remove duplicate , correct you code and then you can easily turn the list into a set like this :

NoDuplicatedList = set(t)

t is the list you want to remove duplicate from .

still you might lose the order of the list you had .